# Vim - Stop buffer number to be automatically incremented everytime a buffer is closed

Tags: vim

For example, I have buffer `foo.c` at `b6`. When I close it with `bd` and open `bar.c` I want `bar.c` to be at `b6` instead of `b7`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not possible; the buffer numbers internally are incremented sequentially; there's no notion of "number reuse" in the current implementation. This would require a code change. An argument against this: Some plugins associate buffer-related information with the buffer number, too. If that number can point to a different buffer, those plugins would be confused.

The only way to get "clean" buffer numbers is to write a *viminfo* or session file, restart Vim, and reload those buffers.